# Why the dipole interaction term in the Hamiltonian has all diagonal elements to be zero in the energy eigenbasis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, matter, semiclassical, laser-interaction

I have been studying the semi-classical light matter interaction from the book, "Light matter interaction" by Weiner and Ho. They have defined the total Hamiltonian of a two level atom placed in an EM radiation as

$$\hat{H}=\hat{H_{0}}+\hat{V}(t)$$

where $H_0$ is the unperturbed Hamiltonian of the two level atom and $\hat{V}(t)$ is the dipole interaction term given by $\hat{V}(t)=\hat{\vec{d}}\cdot\vec{E}$. $\vec{d}$ is the dipole moment of the atom given by $\vec{d}=-e\vec{r}$. The eigenstates of $H_0$ are $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$.

Now, it has been argued that since $V(t)$ has an odd parity with respect to $\vec{r}$, the diagonal terms
$V_{ii}=\langle i|\hat{V}|i \rangle=0$. However, I am not able to understand why this should be so.

**Some thoughts**

Without loss of generality, we can take the dipole moment to be $\hat{\vec{d}}=-e\hat{x} \mathbf{e_x}$ and the driving field $\vec{E}=E_0 cos(\omega t) \mathbf{e_n}$, so that $\hat{V}(t)=-e\hat{x} E_0 cos(\omega t) cos(\phi)$ where $\phi$ is the angle between $\mathbf{e_n}$ and $\mathbf{e_x}$. In such a case, we have

$$V_{ii}=\langle i|\hat{V}|i \rangle=e E_0 cos(\omega t)cos(\phi)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi^{*}_i(\vec{r}) x \phi_i(\vec{r}) d\vec{r}$$

If the wavefunction $\phi^{*}_i(\vec{r})$ has a definite parity(**assumption 1**), then indeed this integral is $0$.

In case of a spherically symmetric potential with no interaction between electrons in the atom, assumption 1 indeed holds. However, in the presence of interaction between electrons, I am not so sure if it will hold true!

Am I thinking about it the right way? Is there a way to prove this without assumption 1? Or is the assumption 1 always true?

Comment: "However, in the presence of interaction, I am not so sure if it will hold true!" - aren't these $\phi(r)$ eigenfunctions of the hamiltonian of an unperturbed atom $H_0$, so you don't have to worry about the interaction?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. By interaction, I mean't the interaction between electrons in the atom rather than the interaction of light with the atom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the wavefunction $\phi^{*}_i(\vec{r})$ has a definite parity (**assumption 1**), then indeed this integral is $0$.

This is the only thing that's going on. We assume that the system is invariant under parity, and therefore that its eigenfunctions have definite parity and therefore that the eigenstates do not have a permanent dipole moment.

For some systems, this assumption can indeed break: notable examples are (the electronic states of) the water and ammonia molecules. If the assumption breaks, then the on-diagonal terms of the interaction potential do need to be included. This is inconvenient, and it makes everything more of a hassle, but it doesn't really introduce any qualitative changes to the physics, which is why it's rarely included unless it's explicitly necessary.

Comment: Note that even time-dependent diagonal part is easily absorbed into the unperturbed Hamiltonian.

Comment: Not as a general statement. In some perturbative regimes, yes, this can be done. But pretending that this can be done in general without hassle is incorrect.

Comment: Mathematically it is always doable. Then one may indeed end up with a time integral that is hard to take. Note also that the symmetry argument works only for atoms and small molecules, but not in solid state.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty the answer makes sense to me. However, it would help if you could provide some references for the water and ammonia examples you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that such terms are usually "absorbed" in the main Hamiltonian, where they represent a small correction to the difference between the energy levels. Note that absorbing the diagonal terms to the Hamiltonian is a rather common procedure, by no means specific to the dipole approximation.

**Example**
E.g., for a two-level system with eigenstates $|1\rangle, |2\rangle$ we have
$$
H=H_0 + V(t) = \begin{bmatrix} E_1 & 0 \\ 0 & E_2\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix} V_{11}(t) & V_{12}(t) \\ V_{21}(t) & V_{22}(t)\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} E_1+V_{11}(t) & 0 \\ 0 & E_2+V_{22}(t)\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & V_{12}(t) \\ V_{21}(t) & 0\end{bmatrix} = H' + V'(t)
$$

**Different energy scales**
If, e.g., we want to calculate the transition probability using the Fermi golden rule, we have
$$
w_{i\rightarrow f} =\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|V_{if}|^2\delta(E_f-E_i\pm \hbar\omega)
$$
As one can see, the role of the non-diagonal and the diagonal elements of the eprturbation is different: the diagonal elements, absorbed into the energies $E_{i,f}$ adjust the energy conservation equality $E_f-E_i\pm \hbar\omega=0$, but this adjustment is small, since in most practical situations $$\left|\frac{V_{ij}}{\hbar\omega}\right|\ll 1, \left|\frac{V_{ij}}{E_2 - E_1}\right|\ll 1.$$

On the other hand, the non-diaginal elements, $V_{if}$, determine the rate of transitions, which cannot be neglected, since it is compared to zero (no transitions at all).